# How can I have my server keep sending information while listining with a timeout

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp, setsockopt

I'm trying to simulate a TCP protocol while using UDP.
I want my server to be able to send chunks of the file the client requested while waiting for acks from the client.

My idea is to send chunk then recv (listen for ack) but that makes it so I can only send chunk nº2 after receiving ack nº1.
Should I just send all of them in a loop and then wait for all the acks in a loop with timeouts?
Or is there way to have recv in the background with a timeout and if it receives an ack it stops the setsockopt timeout feature, and if the timeout occurs it interrupts the current script to resend that chunk?
Edit:
My bad didn't mention it was using C.
OS is linux.

```
Server-Side Libraries:
packet-format.h
arpa/inet.h
limits.h
netinet/in.h
stdbool.h
stddef.h
stdio.h
stdlib.h
string.h
sys/socket.h
unistd.h

Client-Side Libraries:
packet-format.h
limits.h
netdb.h
stdbool.h
stddef.h
stdio.h
stdlib.h
string.h
unistd.h
```

Comment: In what language? On what operating-system? What frameworks or libraries are you using?

Comment: Have you figured out how fast you want to send the chunks? If some router in the connection receives them faster than it can forward them onwards, it might discard some.

Comment: First thing to do is probably figure out how fast you want to send. With UDP, you can't rely on the operating system slowing down your sending to match the connection.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude C, Linux, I updated the post with the libraries.

Comment: @user253751 I want to send a chunk per second, the chunk is 1000 bytes.